# svymultinom in R

Tags: r, regression, glm, multinomial

I'm using a large dataset and have run several logistic regressions with `svyglm()`. I am now examining a dependent variable with at least 5 possible outcomes. I discovered `svymultinom` but I'm having trouble with the code. I get the following error:

```r
mmodel <- svymultinom(outcome3 ~ married, dataDesign)
```

> Error in UseMethod("withReplicates", design) : no applicable method for 'withReplicates' applied to an object of class "c('survey.design2', 'survey.design')"

Can anyone provide an example of how to use `svymultinom`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though `svymultinom` (you should specify the package it's in) works for replicate-weight designs and that your design isn't a replicate-weights design.

I would use the new `svyVGAM` package instead,

```
library(svyVGAM)
mmodel <- svy_vglm(outcome3 ~ married, family=multinomial, design=dataDesign)
```

You could also do

```
svymultinom(outcome3~married, design=as.svrepdesign(dataDesign))
```

but the `svyVGAM::svy_vglm` solution is cleaner

Comment: Thank you, Dr. Lumley.  I just reviewed your documentation for svyVGAM and this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: I ran my model using both svy_vglm and svymultinom, but the results for the two are very different.  I also ran a series of seperate svyglm regressions, and those results were similar to svymultinom.  Why am I getting such drastically different coefficients between svy_vglm and svymultinom?

Comment: Did you set the reference levels for factors to be the same? You might need `multinomial(refLevel=1)`. Otherwise, you'll need to give some actual information about the results

Comment: That's it!  That was what I overlooked.  THANK YOU!